# Blazor Fluent UI boiler plate

Tags: blazor-server-side, fluent-ui

Do anyone know of boiler plate template like https://github.com/siminture/fluentui-starter for blazor server? I am looking for something we can use both for mobile and desktop views in a single template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this: https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate

It supports both WASM and Server however it doesn't use Fluent UI but I would have thought it would be fairly simple to swap MudBlazor out for it with some slight changes to the code.